# Dog rescue - mysql php next prev error when id is less than 0 or after last record

Tags: php, mysql

We have a dog rescue with a new mysql database. It has currently 9 records (or 9 dogs) with id from 1 - 9. YOu can click through them by using next or previous buttons. When id is outside of  1- 9 (like "nothing" or 0") that when we are on record 1 and click prev it cannot find something (cause there is nothing), or when you are on record (or dog) 9 and click next another (or same error) since there are no more records.

Script: (partial)

```
$dog_id = $_GET['id'];
include("conn.inc.php");
// GET THE DOGGY
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pp_dogs WHERE id='$dog_id';");
$dog = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
extract($dog);

// GET NEXT DOGGY
$next_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pp_dogs WHERE id > $dog_id ORDER BY id LIMIT     1;");
$next_dog = mysql_fetch_assoc($next_result);

// GET PREV DOGGY
$prev_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pp_dogs WHERE id < $dog_id ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;");
$prev_dog = mysql_fetch_assoc($prev_result);

mysql_close();
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

> Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /home/content/15/9729315/html/dog_detail.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/content/15/9729315/html/dog_detail.php on line 18
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/content/15/9729315/html/dog_detail.php on line 22

line 13, 18 and 22 are in the script above.

Anyone have a good solution to either disable the next previous buttons when there are no more dogs in the db, or that it goes from 1 (click prev) and go to 9 - the last record?

Answer (score 0):

Start by getting the first and last records, and then use those in your script to either have active or disabled buttons

```
include("conn.inc.php");

// Get first and last records
$first_record = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM pp_dogs ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
$last_record =  mysql_query("SELECT id FROM pp_dogs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
   //Note, mysql_ functions are depreciated. You can use these to test, but you should change to mysqli or PDO

// Get current Dog ID
if ($_GET['id'] < $first_record || $_GET['id'] > $last_record){
   // Either set $dog_id = $first_record OR give message that $dog_id does not exist
}
else {
     $dog_id = $_GET['id'];} //Still need to escape to prevent injection

// GET THE DOGGY
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pp_dogs WHERE id='$dog_id';");
$dog = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
extract($dog);

// GET NEXT DOGGY
if ($dog_id < $last_record){
    $next_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pp_dogs WHERE id > $dog_id ORDER BY id LIMIT     1;");
    $next_dog = mysql_fetch_assoc($next_result);
}
else {
     // Disabled Next Button  ie. <input type="button" value="Next" DISABLED />
     }

// GET PREV DOGGY
if ($dog_id > $first_record){
    $prev_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pp_dogs WHERE id < $dog_id ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;");
     $prev_dog = mysql_fetch_assoc($prev_result);
}
else {
     // Disabled Previous Button  ie. <input type="button" value="Previous" DISABLED />
     }
mysql_close();
```

Also, your current queries are ripe for SQL Injection, and `myslq_` functions should not be used for new development. Change to [mysqli or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) and make sure your safely escaped!

Comment: Thank you Sean for your advice and comments. I will try this in the script and see how it works and let you know. I am a "non-programmer" so this is a little unusual for me, but I am getting by with a little help from my friends. Not sure what mysqli or PDO is, but I will check online. Thank you.

Comment: Sean. I just added your code and tested the page online, and I got an error. Not the same as last time, but trying to access the detail page, the error message is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in /home/content/15/9729315/html/dog_detail.php on line 9 

              Line 9 is where the ASC LIMIT as described below is. // Get first and last records
$first_record = ...("SELECT id FROM pp_dogs ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
$last_record =  ...("SELECT id FROM pp_dogs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
I'm not sure that I did it right, I copied it and pasted it in in the same position online.

Comment: Sorry, the error is caused because I put `...` instead of `mysql_query` before the `"Select..."` queries on 9 & 10, as `mysql` functions are being depreciated. I forgot to add that message in the script. While you are testing you can change line 9 & 10 to `$first_record = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM pp_dogs ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1"); $last_record =  mysql_query("SELECT id FROM pp_dogs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");`. Just be aware that any time you post a `mysql` query on here, you will get comments to change to `mysqli` or `PDO`, which is the current way to run MySQL queries.

Comment: Thank you. I will definitively look into mysqli and PDO. I really appreciate your comments. I will test as soon as I get to my office.

Comment: Sean. Thank you for your consistent help and comments. Unfortunately it seemed not to work for some reason. If you want you can go here: http://www.pekesandpoms.com/db-test.php and then click on the "Dogs for Adoption" link halfway down the page below the main title. Then a grid of 9 dogs comes up. I updated the page that comes up when you click on one of the dogs with your code. Now click the next or previous buttons until you see the error messages I get. Seems like we are back to the first error messages I had initially. Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: the error is because you next/previous links are missing the dog id - `http://www.pekesandpoms.com/dog_detail.php?id= `. So when you click on the link, there is no `id` in your query to your database. What is your code to create the `<a href="http://www.pekesandpoms.com/dog_detail.php?id="></a>` around the next/previous buttons? It looks like the `next` work on 1-3, but not 4-9, the `previous` don't work 1-3, but is set as 1 on 4-9. There must be something wrong in how you are setting the `id` variable.